# Resumable Upload with ng-file-upload + PHP (Merging parts)

Tags: php, file-upload, ng-file-upload, chunks

I'm trying to implement [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) with Resumable Uploads mode to split big files in chunks and merge them once uploaded. I have implemented ng-file-upload in many projects but it's my first time doing it to upload so big files.

My issue is that I don't know how to make it work the server side files in PHP. I've just got to upload chunks with diferents name but I can't merge them.

Could anybody post an example of server side code in PHP to make work this feature?

This is what I have done up to this point:

AngularJS

```
$scope.uploadMediaFile = function (file) {

        if(file) {

            Upload.upload({
                ignoreLoadingBar: true,
                url: 'app/api/upload/mediaFile.php',
                resumeChunkSize: '1MB',
                file: file
            }).then(function (response) {
                if(response.data.success) {
                    $scope.post.mediaFile = response.data.filename;
                    $scope.post.duration = response.data.duration;
                } else {
                    console.error(response.data.error);
                }
            }, null, function (evt) {
                console.log(part);
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
    };
```

mediaFile.php

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$file_ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$file_des = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/storage/content/temp/';

if(!file_exists($file_des)) mkdir($file_des);

// Puting a diferent name for each file part
$new_filename = uniqid() . "." . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_des . $new_filename)
```

So far, I get many pieces of same file with diferent names.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is looking similar question, I post my solution.

```
<?php
// File chunk
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


// Defining temporary directory

$file_des = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/storage/content/temp/';

// If not exists, create temp dir.
if(!file_exists($file_des)) mkdir($file_des);

// The first chunk have the original name of file uploaded
// so, if it exists in temp dir, upload the other pieces 
// with anothers uniques names
if(file_exists($file_des . $filename)) {

    $new_name = uniqid() . "." . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_des . $new_name);

    // Now, append the chunk file to the first base file.
    $handle = fopen($file_des . $new_name, 'rb');
    $buff = fread($handle, filesize($file_des . $new_name));
    fclose($handle);

    $final = fopen($file_des . $filename, 'ab');
    $write = fwrite($final, $buff);
    fclose($final);

    // Delete chunk
    unlink($file_des . $new_name);

} else {

    /* MAKE SURE WE DELETE THE CONTENT OF THE DESTINATION FOLDER FIRST, 
       OTHERWISE CHUNKS WILL BE APPENDED FOR EVER 
       IN CASE YOU ARE TRYING TO UPLOAD A FILE WITH THE EXACT SAME NAME. 
       CAREFUL: YOU MAY PREFER TO DELETE ONLY THE FILE 
       INSTEAD OF THE FOLDER'S CONTENT, IN THE CASE 
       YOUR FOLDER CONTAINS MORE THAN ONE FILE.
    */

    $files_to_delete = glob($file_des."*"); // get all file names
    foreach($files_to_delete as $file) // iterate files
    { 
      if(is_file($file))
      {
        unlink($file); // delete file
      }
    }


    // First chunk of file with original name.
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_des . $filename);
}
```